# Cypher create path in single query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to create the following path in a single cypher query?

Path:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3WHeKW1--8qajZRQmlBN082UG8/view?usp=sharing

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that you can use as many CREATE and MERGE blocks as you like.

```
CREATE (a), (b), (c)
MERGE (a)-[:foo]->(b)
MERGE (a)-[:foo]->(c)
RETURN a,b,c;
```

Comment: If this is the right answer, please mark the question answered.